# Can not load xml file in xml document.load

Tags: xml, xaml, windows-8.1

I have fruit list in xml file. I want to load this xml file so that I can read the data stored in xmlfiles. I have the path where I stored my xml file but when I try to load the xml file I get an error. Is there any way to load the data from the xml file?

```cs
Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///XMLFile/XMLHistory.xml");
// (here in dataUri have path of xml file)
StorageFile file = await  
StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(stream); // (here i get error)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I forgot to renew my crystal ball contract...

Comment: Improved english (grammar, capitalisation, etc) ; also added syntax highlighting to the code snippet, and marked up the commentary as code comments.